# Enabled Mode Compatibily in Webview UWP Win 8.1

Tags: c#, webview, uwp

Is it possible for me to force my page to display in Internet Explorer 8 compatibility mode within the Webview of a UWP Windows 8.1 application?

Today my web application receives a request via POST and displays content compatible only with Internet Explorer 8 :(

Code Web View:

```
<WebView x:Name="MyWebView" Source="" />
```

Code  C# UWP:

```
string url = "https://www.exampleapp.net/app/";  

string postBody = string.Format("keyvalue=param1&keyvalue2={0}", someValue);  

StringContent postBodyEncoded = new StringContent(postBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  

HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();  

handler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

HttpClient client  = new HttpClient(handler);     

HttpResponseMessage res = await client.PostAsync(url, postBodyContent);  

var content = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 

MyWebView.NavigateToString(content);
```

My Page:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
      <title>My Web Page</title>
      <script src="https://www.exampleapp.net/app/script.js"></script>       
  </head>
   <body>
      <p>Dynamic Content.</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible for me to force my page to display in Internet Explorer 8 compatibility

Derive from [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview#windows8), You could not  force the page to display in Internet Explorer 8 compatibility mode.

For requirement, you could save the content to html file and open it with Edge Browser. And the set the Edge compatibility mode like the following.

[image]